# Wrapping shortcodes in a tel: link

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, shortcode

We're using custom fields to replace all telephone numbers on a page and we'd like them to be clickable by making them 'tel:' links.

Is there something I can add to the htaccess file to make this happen site wide any time a page renders [phone_number]?

Thanks in advance.

I tried wrapping a shortcode directly within the page and the number doesn't display on the link and is not clickable.

```
<a href="tel:[phone_number]">[phone_number]</a>
```

Edit: the number is visible and clickable but the tel: field is empty, it'll open the caller app but it's empty.

Comment: This is possible using the "substitute" module available for the apache http server. But I would recommend against such a strategy. It require that module, so the option is only available if you operate the http server yourself, the approach is "exotic", so few examples are available. It adds complexity and spreads the application logic over different locations. And finally: clickable telefone links are somewhat exotic themselves - do you _really_ have lots of users able to make constructive use of such links? Consider too that such rendering makes copying the numbers much harder ...

Comment: So this is about WordPress, yes? (Then you should tag/mention that.) What does the shortcode function actually look like, what _exact_ return value does it give?